# Add `lang-makefile` language hint to [makefile] tag

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

It seems like https://stackoverflow.com/tags/makefile/info is not associated with any "code language". It should use `lang-makefile` by default.

Comment: lang-makefile is supported by the highlight.js config SE uses, and I don't see many questions where there would be conflict between other tags with highlighting hints so a mod could add this with little risk of unwanted side-effects.

Comment: So, fun fact: we can't actually do this. The dropdown selection box for setting the default syntax highlighting for a tag doesn't include `lang-makefile` as one of the choices. That selection box is clearly using a hardcoded list of values, and it hasn't been updated after the switch to Highlight.JS.

Comment: Also note: The backend processing checks to make sure the value submitted is one of those which was already included in the dropdown (i.e. just changing the HTML to add another language or making an AJAX request with the desired language doesn't work). The list of available selections has to be changed by SE.

Comment: @Makyen Maybe these kinds of `feature-request` items can be linked to one canonical meta-question about _"Update list of lang- values in SE to reflect the current full list available in Highlight.js"_